# Empty value in a IN clause with select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use empty value in an `IN` clause. But following queries don't work identically.

```
SELECT * from tblTest WHERE colName IN  ( '') 

SELECT * from tblTest WHERE colName IN (SELECT '''''')
```

The first works fine but the second has no error but gives empty result.

Comment: Why do you want to that?

Comment: "but gives empty result" . . . That is the result I would expect if `in` had an empty list.

Comment: Also, if you have a working solution, what's this question about?

Comment: colName is varchar. some rows with empty ('') values. i just want to select those. so i can use fist query. but the problem is i want to pass that value as a CSV. so i have to use select statement in side the IN clause. the i pass '' to select it want give any result

Answer (score 2):

It's because `SELECT ''''''` will return you `''` and try to compare your values to it, which is not an empty string.
Anyway, it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty clear: you want the rows where the column contains an empty string. But if you compare with (select '''''') you dont select an empty string! You select a string that looks like this: ''

This works:

```
SELECT * from tblTest WHERE colName IN (SELECT '')
```